# How to get iPad setting programmatically (not application settings)

Tags: objective-c

How I can get iPad setting programmatically (not application settings)
Like if bluetooth On or of, DateTime set Automatically, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That wont work. Some stuff will work, like getting basic device specific properties, such as Battery Level, device Name, etc.
But you can't turn on BLuetooth/Wifi without using private frameworks and then, Apple will probably reject your App. To get the device properties, have a look at the `UIDevice` class.

Comment: I see an application that can detect if multitasking gestures enabled or not, how I can get this ? and why I can't get anther settings just to check the value without change it ?